# Java pattern and matcher randomly breaks

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I am trying to read the browser language and the get the first occurance of xx-XX (eg: en-US) from the long string returned.

```
final String delimiter = "([a-z]{2})-([a-z]{2})";
final String language = (request.getHeader("Accept-Language")).toLowerCase();
String locale = "";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(delimiter);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(language);

if(matcher.find()) {
    locale = matcher.group(0); 
}
```

String `locale` gets values like this:

`de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-AU;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,en-US;q=0.2,en-GB;q=0.2,en-NZ;q=0.2,fr-FR;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2,en-CA;q=0.2`

I am trying to get the first one, in this case 'de-DE'. Some random times it breaks for reasons I cant comprehend. The application itself breaks. The build works fine. I have tracked it down this code (removed everything else on the page). Still not sure what the issue is. Any tips?

Comment: Do you have an exception? My guess is that it will be NullPointerException - the "Accept-Language" is not set sometimes?

Comment: "Some random times" I'm sure it's not really random. What is the input when it breaks? (I can believe you sometimes get a `NullPointerException`, if there is no `Accept-Language` header).

Comment: Also, if you're trying to find `de-DE`, you'll need to include `A-Z` in your character class.

Comment: You know servlets have [a method for this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale--), right?

Comment: The regex was a typo when I typed in here. That was a good suggestion on `NullPointerException`. I now have a `if(language != null){` . That seems to work

Answer (score 1):

What about regexp like this:

```
([a-z]{2})(\-[A-Z]{2})?
```

In that case, the 2nd part is optional.

[This page](https://regex101.com/) can help you with testing regexps.